# Wait for state update useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I have an array of objects in state: `const [objects, setObjects] = useState([]);`

I have an add button that adds an object to the array, this is the body of the onclick event:

`setObjects([...objects, {
   id: 20,
   property1: value1
}]);`

I have a remove button that removes an object from the array, this is the body of the onclick event:

`const newObjects = objects.filter(object => {
   return object.id !== idToRemove; // idToRemove comes from the onclick event
});
setObjects(newObjects);`

Now I want to do something with the updated state if an object gets removed from the state.

The problem is I have to wait till the state is updated and I don't want to listen for every state change, only if something is removed.

This is what I have so far:

`useEffect(() => {
    //execute a function that uses the updated state
}, [objects.length]);`

But this also fires of if an object gets added to the state.

In short: **I want to do something when an object gets removed from the objects array and the state is finished updating**

I would like to do this with hooks.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you're trying to do? Why not do this in the function that removes objects from the array?

Comment: @CelsoWellington Because I have to execute this after the state is finished updating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own hook or add some other variable that will keep the array's length and which could be used to check whether element was removed or added.

```
const [len, setLen] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  if (objects.length < len) {
    // Your code
  }

  setLen(objects.length);
}, [objects.length]);
```